# Can a power series always be integrated term-by-term inside the circle of convergence of its sum function?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Is it true that a *power series* can always be integrated term-by-term inside (i.e. in the interior of) the circle of convergence of its sum/limit function?

My complex analysis textbook merely states this as a remark, and of the six real analysis textbooks I've consulted (including Rudin and Spivak), only one explcitly states this; the rest only give that term-by-term differentiation is allowed.

Comment: Read here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformConvergence.html.

Comment: Issac Thanks, but I wasn't able to surmise anything useful for my purposes from that post.

Comment: I've changed the link to something more useful (I hope)!

Comment: Uniform convergence lets you switch limits, and you can think of the integral as being given by a limit (in the sense of Riemann sums).

Comment: @Issac Thanks again, yes, I've just spent the entire day reading up on uniform convergence, etc. and I believe the answer to my question should be Yes, but I would like someone more learned to verify my understanding, since as I pointed out, most of the excellent textbooks I've consulted strangely seem to avoid giving the counterpart theorem for integration of *power series* while giving much space to differntiation of *power series* (as opposed to a general series). I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: @Issac Might it be because the integration case (due to uniform convergence) is supposed to be an obvious corollary whereas the differentiation case is less clearcut and thus more deserving of exposition?

Comment: Yes, as you'll see in the link above, the situation is more complicated for differentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same property, once you already know that formal differentiation doesn't change the radius of convergence.

If of you have one power series $F$ with radius of convergence $R$, you can at least *write down* what ought to result from integrating it term by term. What you get is undoubtedly a power series $G$ for *something*, and the formal *derivative* of $G$ is $F$. Therefore $F$ and $G$ have the same radius of convergence, so inside that radius $F$ is also the *actual* derivative of $G$, by the result that you find in all the textbooks. But that means exactly that $G$ is an actual primitive function for $F$, so integration term-for-term works within the disc of convergence.

Comment: Yes, the only of my real-analysis texts explicitly giving the case for integration proves it using the Fundamental Thm of Calculus too (uniform convergence isn't in the scope of that text). The complex analysis text OTOH gives the case for integration as a consequence of the uniform convergence theorem. Thank you, Henning.